# Having trouble with launch.json in Visual studio code

Tags: java, debugging

I am working with Java interfaces and when I'm writing the main method some issues coming up in VS code suddenly.

It does not prevent the execution but instead, it keeps showing some error message in the VS problem section.

[image]

When I click on Debug I get the below errors.

[image]

[image]

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix this?

Comment: `new sample()` - what on earth is `sample`?

Comment: But anyway, please do not post code as an image.  Also, this seems to be a setup problem with VS. for a start the jdkPath does not seem to be set

Comment: "sample" is the class that defines the now() method. It's strange because I never had a setup issue until now and I googled it but didn't find any solution for this issue so far.

Comment: Hi ,Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Especially see [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: The program is executing fine but it keeps showing me "Build failed, do you want to continue?" message.  [ same problem](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/495)

Comment: Also VSC for Java is really ...uncommon. I have seen it only once in my life but it sure will make problems. I suggest to use a more common IDE for Java, like IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-debuggers

The format seems to be

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
      {
        "type": "mock",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "mock test",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/readme.md",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "debugServer": 4711
      }
    ]
}
```

so you are missing `{` after `[` and `}` before `]`,

If you had **not** posted an image, I could have edited it for you.

Comment: I tried putting "{" but that didn't resolve the issue. The program is executing fine but it keeps showing me "Build failed, do you want to continue?" message.  [ same problem](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/495)